# Operator norm $4$ different definitions how to prove that $\sup$ is $\max$ and $\inf$ is $\min$ for the last two?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, spectral-norm

From what I have understood, all the $\sup$'s and $\inf$'s in the $4$ different definitions of the operator norm can be taken as $\max$'s and $\min$'s.

For a linear map $A\in \mathscr L (V,W)$ between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ (of the form $\mathbb R^k$):
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \inf\{ c\;\colon\; \lVert Av\rVert\leq c\lVert v\rVert \text{ for all }v\in V\}\\
S_1&=\sup\{ \lVert Av\rVert\;\colon\; v\in V\text{ with }\lVert v\rVert\leq 1\}\\
S_2&=\sup\{\lVert Av\rVert\;\colon\; v\in V\text{ with }\lVert v\rVert = 1 \}\\
S_3&=\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert Av\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}\;\colon\; v\in V\text{ with }v\neq 0\right\}.
\end{align*}$$

As $\{ x\in V \mid ||x|| \leq 1\}$ and $\{ x\in V \mid ||x|| = 1\}$ are compact, as the composition of the absolute value with $A$ is continuous and as this composition is a real-valued function, we can conclude that the $\sup$ is attained, and hence is the same as the $\max$ for $S_1$ and $S_2$.

For $S_3$ , I don't see why the $\sup$ would be equal to the $\max$. The function considered is $|\frac{A}{Id}|$ and the domain is $V\backslash \{0\}$. As far as I know, $V\backslash \{0\}$ is not compact (since it is unbounded).

I have the same problem for $I$ (proving that the $\inf$ is the $\min$).

Thanks in advance.

PS: I also am wondering if the vector spaces $V$ and $W$ can be of an other form than $\mathbb R^k$. But I doubt so, because then we could not argue that $\{ x\in V \mid ||x|| \leq 1\}$ and $\{ x\in V \mid ||x|| = 1\}$ are compact.

Comment: Hint: Use linearity of $A$ and homogeneity of the norm to show that a maximal element in $S_2$ is also a maximal element in $S_3$. Similar reasoning can be applied to show that there is a minimum for $I$. The statement remains valid in any finite dimensional vector space (use an isomorphism).

Comment: Referring to your PS: Indeed, all of this holds without the vector spaces being finite dimensional. However, the reasoning about the supremum being attained due compactness of the unit ball and the unit sphere will fail.

Comment: @jd27 so your point is using the equivalence of these definitions, to say that (for example between $I$ and $S_2$) the $\min$ is attained because the $\max$ of the equivalent definition is attained ?

Comment: For $I$ it'll always be a minimum no matter the dimensions and no matter the operator, but for the $\sup$s there are operators for which there is no maximiser $v$.

Comment: @niobium yes, that is what i mean.

Comment: @jd27 What if we took $I= \inf (\mathbb R ^{+*}) = 0 \neq \min (\mathbb R ^{+*})$ and $J= \sup(\mathbb R^{-} ) = 0 = \max (\mathbb R^{-} )$. My point is that an $\inf$ definition can be equal to a $\sup$ definition but at the same time $\sup = \max$ doesn't imply $\inf = \min$

Comment: @niobium i am not saying that this is some general relation between infima/suprema and minima/maxima. It follows here from the specific conditions. For example to go from $S_2$ to $I$ let $u$ be the maximum. Then $ \| A v \|  \leq \| Au \| \|v \| $ for all $v \in V$. Therefore $\|Au\|$ is one of the $c$'s in the infimum and $\|Au\| \geq I$. But we also have $\|Au \| \leq c \|u \| = c$ for all the $c$'s in the infimum and therefore $\|Au\|$ is the infimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your first question: the $\sup$ can be turned into a $\max$ because the set $$\left\{\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} : x\neq 0\right\} = \{\|Ax\| : \|x\| = 1\}$$ is compact.

To address your second question, indeed we can consider other spaces than $\mathbb R^n$. One such type of space is called a [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space). Formally, a Banach space is a vector space $V$ equipped with a norm $\|\cdot\|$ such that the metric $d(x,y) := \|x-y\|$ generates a complete metric space. Frequently encountered Banach spaces are the $L^p$ spaces on $\mathbb R^n$, i.e.,
$$L^p(\mathbb R^n) := \left\{f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R : \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|^p\,d\mu < \infty\right\},$$
with the associated norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ defined by
$$\|f\|_p := \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}.$$
Here $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. In the special case of $L^2$ it turns out that $\|\cdot\|_2$ is generated by the inner product
$$(f,g) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} fg\,d\mu, \quad \|f\|_2 = \sqrt{(f,f)}.$$
This leads us to a second popular way to study spaces other than $\mathbb R^n$: [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space). A Hilbert space $V$ is a Banach space where the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is generated by an inner product; i.e., there is an inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ such that $\|x\| = \sqrt{(x,x)}$ for all $x\in V$.

It is still possible (and in fact, useful) to define operator norms on a Banach space $V$. In fact, they are defined exactly the same. In particular, if $T : V \to V$ is a linear operator, then $\|T\|_{op} < \infty$ if and only if $T$ is continuous, where $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ is the operator norm.

Indeed, your observation that $\{x \in V : \|x\| = 1\}$ is not compact holds whenever $V$ is infinite dimensional, by [Riesz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma#Some_consequences).

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a way (my way) of proving that for $I$, the $\inf$ is equal to the $\min$:

$\{ c\;\colon\; \lVert Av\rVert\leq c\lVert v\rVert \text{ for all }v\in V\}$ $=$ $\{ c\;\colon\; \lVert Av\rVert\leq c  \text{ for all }v\in V,\text{ such that } \lVert v \lVert = 1\}$ (to see this, just divide the inequality by $\lVert v \lVert$).

The last set is nothing more than $F^{-1} ([0,c])$ with $F = \lVert A \lVert$ (the composition of absolute value with $A$), intersected with the compact set $\{v\in V \text{ such that } \lVert v \lVert = 1\}$.

Hence $\{ c\;\colon\; \lVert Av\rVert\leq c\lVert v\rVert \text{ for all }v\in V\}$ is a part of $\mathbb R$, bounded from below (by $0$) and closed ; we conclude that $\inf\{ c\;\colon\; \lVert Av\rVert\leq c\lVert v\rVert \text{ for all }v\in V\}$ belongs to the set and hence is a $\min$.